# Better understanding of (log n) time complexity

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, big-o

I'm a bit confused on (log n). Given this code

```
public static boolean IsPalindrome(String s) {
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < (chars.length / 2); i++) {
        if (chars[i] != chars[(chars.length - i - 1)])
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am looping n/2 times. So, as length of n increase, my time is increasing half the time of n. In my opinion, I thought that's exactly what log n was? But the person who wrote this code said this is still O(N).

In what case of a loop, can something be (log n)? For example this code:

```
1. for (int i = 0; i < (n * .8); i++)
```

Is this log n? I'm looping 80% of n length.

What about this one?

```
2. for (int i = 1; i < n; i += (i * 1.2))
```

Is that log n? If so, why.

Comment: The last thing is an *O(log n)*. (1) is just *O(n)*.

Comment: The time complexity is typically talking about the size of input, here for a string of size n it takes O(n) operations so the complexity is O(n), what you're talking about is like the growth which is different, The last one is log(n) since it takes log_1.2(n) operations or so to go through the loop, which (provided the body of the loop has not too many operations) imples the complexity is O(log(n))

Comment: Are you familiar with logarithms?

Comment: O(n/2) is the same as O(n) but a log is a different thing altogether.  For example, a base 10 log tells you how many digits are in the number: log(1) = 0, log(10) = 1, log(100) = 2, log(10000000000) = 10  So you see that with an O(log(n)) algorithm if you loop 100 times you can process a google items (10^100) which is very different from dividing.

Comment: The complexity is simply defining the number of operations variation compared to the number of entry elements. The first example is a linear relation (a line on a graph) between the number of characters and the how many loops. 
In the last example the step interval on the `for` loop is increasing by 20% for each step, which means that over time is it getting bigger and therefore decreasing the number of steps in a exponential manner hence a logarithmic complexity.
So you could have two algorithms with O(n) but one looping n/2 times and the second looping n/4 times.

Comment: A small correction  though.... your last loop example is an infinite loop since the starting value of `i`is 0 and `0 + 0 * 1.2 = 0` so there is no increment! So my previous comment is only valid for a non-zero starting value and an increment like `i = i * 1.2`

Comment: @user10472446 great catch, fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1. for (int i = 0; i < (n * .8); i++)`
In the first case basically you can replace 0.8n with another variable, let's call it m.

`for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)` You're looping m number of times. You're increasing value of `i` one unit in each iteration. Since `m` and `n` are just variable names, the Big-O complexity of the above loop is O(n).

`2. for (int i = 0; i < n; i += (i * 1.2))`
In the second scenario, you're not incrementing the value of `i`, the value of `i` is always going to be `0`. And it is a classic case of an for-infinite loop.

What you're looking for is `2. for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += (i * 1.2))` Here, you're incrementing the value of i logarithmically(but not to the base 2).

Consider `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += i)` The value of i doubles after every iteration. value of i is going to be `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64..` Let's say n value is 64, your loop is going to terminate in 7 iterations, which is `(log(64) to the base 2) + 1`(`+1` because we are starting the loop from 1) number of operations. Hence it becomes a logarithmic operation.

`2. for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += (i * 1.2))` In your case as well the solution is a logarithmic solution, but it is not to the base 2. The base of your logarithmic operation is `2.2`, But in big-O notation it boils down to a `O(log(n))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss what is [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) and how the [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) work.

The Big O notation is used to describe the ***asymptotic*** behavior of the algorithm as the size of the problem growth (to infinity). Particular coefficients do not matter.

As a simple intuition, if when you increase `n` by a factor of `2`, the number of steps you need to perform also increases by about `2` times, it is a linear time complexity or what is called `O(n)`.

So let's get back to your examples #1 and #2:

1. yes, you do only `chars.length/2` loop iterations but if the length of the `s` is doubled, you also double the number of iterations. This is exactly the linear time complexity
2. similarly to the previous case you do `0.8*n` iterations but if `n` is doubled, you do twice as many iterations. Again this is linear

The last example is different. The coefficient `1.2` doesn't really matter. What matters is that you add `i` to itself. Let's re-write that statement a bit

```
i += (i * 1.2)
```

is the same as

```
i = i + (i * 1.2)
```

which is the same as

```
i = 2.2 * i
```

Now you clearly see that each iteration you more than double `i`. So if you double `n` you'll only need one more iteration (or even the same). This is a sign of a fundamentally sub-linear time complexity. And yes this is an example of `O(log(n))` because for a big `n` you need only about `log(n, base=2.2)` iterations and it is true that

```
 log(n, base=a) = log(n, base=b) / log(n, base=b) = constant * log(x, base=b)
```

where `constant` is `1/log(a, base=b)`